# What exactly is SPLIT_BUNDLE 4 and SPLIT_BUNDLE 5 on ad fraud. I added new ads to my new update, is it illegal?

Tags: admob

Added new ads to the new update, is it illegal? AdMob already approved my app. I need to know whether it's illegal to add new ads to the app on an update.

I'm also preserving my splash screen till the AppOpenAd is loaded, then removing it just before the ad is shown. Can this also be a problem.

[image: Email screenshot]

Comment: Same issue in one of my client's apps. Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: This was among my first apps on the app store, I was still learning, the SPLIT BUNDLE referred to the APK itself, and nothing specific. It just meant the specific APK had the specified problem.